# What is the "|" character in Django called?

Tags: python, django

"|" is equivalent to Angular Pipes but what is it called in Django? Like in the official Django Polls App tutorial

[image]

`vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}` is to let Django automatically appends an "s" character after the string "vote" if there are more than 2 votes being rendered from the databse, otherwise don't but I don't know what is called in Django. On another hand, this equivalent technology in Angular is called Angular Pipes.

Comment: This is a template filter.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [*pipe character* (`|`) [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar). The part include the name of a function is a [*(template) filter* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#filters).

Django has [*builtin template filters* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/), but you can write a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) yourself.

The items between `{% … %}` on the other hand are [*(template) tags* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#tags).